# How to get only the value from the SQL query output without parentheses

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store, sqlresultsetmapping, flask-mysql

Here is my code in the flask app

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASWPRD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'customer'

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
     cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
     cur.execute("SELECT City FROM customer")
     data = cur.fetchall()
     cur.close()
   return render_template ("index.html", name=data)
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

which returns this

Hello World
(('DHK',), ('KHL',), ('RAJ',), ('COM',))

But I want to show like this 
DHK, KHL,......

How can I get this and use it in HTML template

## **UPDATE**

Here is the index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flask App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <head>Hello World</head>
    
    <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please provide index.html template? I believe the answer would be there

Comment: I added the file under the  "UPDATE"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this? I think you need to loop arround this value you pass to the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flask App</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <head>Hello World</head>

    {% for message in name %}
      {% for item in message %}
        {{ item }},
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's Showing this >>>   Hello World
('DHK',), ('KHL',), ('RAJ',), ('COM',),